# JYAML: Serialize/deserialize nested/inner classes

Tags: java, yaml, inner-classes, jyaml

First of all, Merry Christmas to everyone!

Now to my question:
Let's say I have the class `Outer` with some inner class Inner. As a field in `Outer`, I have a `List<Inner>`, which i then want to dump to a YAML file. I do this like so:

```
Outer o = new Outer();
o.innerList = new ArrayList<Inner>();
o.innerList.add(new o.Inner());
...
Yaml.dump(o, new File("test.yml");
```

This gives me the exception: `Exception in thread "main" org.ho.yaml.exception.ObjectCreationException: Error near line 0: Can't create object of type class game.Outer$Inner using default constructor.`

I tried providing a custom constructor and changing the access level to public, to no help. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SnakeYAML has a lot of examples with inner classes.
How does the YAML document (test.yml) look like ?
Is Inner a static inner class ?

Comment: I'm trying to serialize to see how the output will look like, in order to create my own documents for parsing. No, Inner is not static. I will have a look at SnakeYAML.

Comment: I am afraid it is not possible if the inner class is not static. There is not way to represent the link to its parent in a YAML document.

Comment: You may try to serialize to XML first to see whether it is visible.
If it possible to create XML it is possible to create YAML.

Comment: I tried SnakeYAML and it seems to be working if I add a public modifier to the class. It even seems to be working if I put a static modifier to the class.

Answer (score 0):

First thing is check that YAML supports the Inner class serialization.